# Перенаправление не работает при использовании URLConnection в Android

Tags: java, android

`URLConnection` обращается к странице, которая автоматически перенаправляется на другую страницу. Всё нормально работало на Java SE, но когда перенес этот метод на Android, перенаправление перестало работать. Почему оно не срабатывает в Android?

Comment: Код покажи.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заработало после того как я параметры url пропустил через URLEncoder
`URLConnection connection=URL("https://site.com/"+URLEncoder.encode("параметр","UTF-8")).openConnection();`

Answer (score 1):

А редирект явно пробовали разрешать?

```
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

Или глобально, есть статический метод

```
URLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

Но насколько я помню, он должен быть разрешен по умолчанию. Но есть ограничения:

- не больше 5 переходов
- переходы HTTPS->HTTP не поддерживаются

И в разных версиях Андроида, до версии 4 и 4+, поведение может отличаться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пробовал но ошибка оказалась очень глупой и была в другом, я не декодировал параметры URL. Вызвал для них URLEncoder.encode прицепил к основному адресу и все заработало. Но в java SE и без этого все работало.